# Groovy Spring @Configuration using @ComponentScan with multiple packages

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I am using groovy and `@ComponentScan` with-in a `@Configuration`

Groovy syntax does not allow for `{"foo","bar"}` for in-lining String Arrays.  How do I get multiple packages?

In java

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.igive.services","com.igive.camel"})
```

How can I do this in groovy??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the Groovy `List` notation

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.igive.services","com.igive.camel"])
```

Comment: Actually I can see the bean name in the debug logs, I am having another problem